# NSArray! is not identical to UInt8 when I am using NSString

Tags: ios, swift, casting, nsarray

I am building a chat app, where I get all the messages from the server in json format. The result is:

```
{"success":"true","userid":"2","messages":[{"id":"1","senderid":"1","receiverid":"2","message":"Hey there!"},{"id":"2","senderid":"1","receiverid":"2","message":"How are you?"},{"id":"3","senderid":"1","receiverid":"2","message":"Hey "},{"id":"4","senderid":"1","receiverid":"2","message":"Hey"},{"id":"5","senderid":"1","receiverid":"2","message":"Yo!"},{"id":"6","senderid":"1","receiverid":"2","message":"Yo!"},{"id":"7","senderid":"1","receiverid":"2","message":"asd"},{"id":"8","senderid":"2","receiverid":"1","message":"Leave me alone!"}]}
```

I am trying to receive the `message` of each item, and display it in a tableview.

I have an `NSArray` for my table view currently holding nothing, but when it calls the `getMessages()` method, I want to populate the array with all the messages.

Here is my code:

```
var content: AnyObject! = jsonData.valueForKey("messages")
for message in content as [NSDictionary] {
    if let m = message["message"] as? [NSString] {
        listDataArray += m
    }
}
```

but it throws the error:

```
'NSArray!' is not identical to 'UInt8'
```

on the line:

```
listDataArray += m
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should `append` to array.`+=` operator is used to add elemenets from array

```
 listDataArray.append(m)
```

If it is `NSArray` make it `NSMutableArray`

```
  //Change where listDataArray declared
  var listDataArray:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

  //addthe objects
  listDataArray.addObject(m)
```

Comment: It says `'NSArray' does not have a member named 'append'`

Comment: @JoshHarington you need to make it mutable array.Edited answer have a look.

Comment: I thought I tried that before and it didnt work. Either way it works now, Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

The fixed code to append to the `listDataArray` is:

```
if let m = message["message"] as? NSString {
    listDataArray += [m]
}
```

The error is that `message["message"]` is a string, not an array of strings.

I don't know if you were trying to automatically convert a string into an array containing that string with this code:

```
if let m = message["message"] as? [NSString] {
```

if yes, that doesn't work...

Note the usage of the `+=` operator, which appends all elements of the array at the right side to the array at the left side - that's why the variable `m` is enclosed in an array: `[m]`

---

It turns out your `listDataArray` is an `NSMutableArray` (isn't it?), in that case the code to add to the array is simply:

```
if let m = message["message"] as? NSString {
    listDataArray.addObject(m)
}
```

Comment: I still get the error `'NSArray!' is not identical to 'UInt8'`

Comment: I am not using an `NSMutableArray`. When I change it to that, I get the error `found nil when unwrapping optional` but when I print it out, it shows the message?

Comment: Hard to figure out - you should post all related code in your question, at least where `listDataArray` is declared

Comment: If it's not a swift array and it's not a `NSMutableArray`, then what is it?

Comment: I excluded that by default... a `NSArray` is immutable, so you cannot add elements. It has to be either a `NSMutableArray`, or a swift array

Comment: So if you have this error `found nil when unwrapping optional` using a mutable array, that's probably because you skipped the optional binding/cast - see updated code in answer